# Team and players objects Java difficulties

Tags: java, object

Basically I'm trying to get my head around creating a java program that manages teams and players.

From my understanding I would have a team and a player class. In the team class there would be the get and set methods, as well as some form of collection to store the players in right, such as an array list? Then in the player class the relevant get and set methods.

This setup would be because one team have one to many players right?

I've had no end of trouble trying to get this working. One particular problem I've encountered is that every time I create a team object, and add a player object to it, then create another team object and another player but if I list the players for that new team it shows the previous player added to the first team as well as the new player.

So I figured it was back to the drawing board and wondered if someone could offer some general advice about how they would structure this?

Many thanks,

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class test {
public test() {
}

//Method to show the team and its players

public static void showTeamPlayers(Team aTeam) {
    Player players;
    System.out.println(aTeam.getTeamName());
    Iterator e = aTeam.getPlayerList().iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        players = (Player)e.next();
        System.out.println("\t" + players.getPlayerNumber() + " " + players.getPlayerName());
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int teamID;
    String teamName = "";

    //First create a divison/league
    League DivisionOne = new League("Division One");

    //Create a new team object
    Team team = new Team(teamName);

    //Asks the user to enter a team name and stores the input
    UserInput.print("Enter team name:");
    teamName = UserInput.readString();

    team.setTeamName(teamName);

    //Add the team
    DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));

    Player player = new Player(0, "Dave");
    Player player1 = new Player(1, "Dennis");
    Player player2 = new Player(2, "Peter");

    //Add to team
    team.addPlayer(player);
    team.addPlayer(player1);
    team.addPlayer(player2);

    test.showTeamPlayers(team);

    //Asks the user to enter a team name and stores the input
    UserInput.print("Enter team name:");
    teamName = UserInput.readString();

    team.setTeamName(teamName);

    //Add the team
    DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));

    Player player3 = new Player(3, "Creamer");
    Player player4 = new Player(4, "Matt");
    Player player5 = new Player(5, "John");

    //Add to team 1
    team.addPlayer(player3);
    team.addPlayer(player4);
    team.addPlayer(player5);

    test.showTeamPlayers(team);
}
}
```

Comment: You should post some code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It would help if you post your code so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure should be totally right this way (and btw, "one to many associations" are described with "1:n" or "1:(1..n)" ).

Either you have definitely a bug somewhere in your code (post it ;)), for example a static field or used an identifier twice, or you could maybe run into problems with an ArrayList here (try LinkedList for test purposes), but I'm not sure at that.

EDIT:
You forgot to post your model, we're only seeing the test of it, but there you got already a few bugs:

```
Team team = new Team(teamName);
teamName = UserInput.readString();
team.setTeamName(teamName);
```

So far, so good. Except that its senseless, to create an instance of Team with an empty teamName and then reset it afterwards, but nvm....

```
DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));
```

Babam, you're not adding your created Team instance above to DivisionOne, no you're creating a new one. Actually, thats Bug No.1

```
team.addPlayer(player);
team.addPlayer(player1);
team.addPlayer(player2);
```

But you're putting the new players to the instance you created above, they're not getting to the team which is created for DivisionOne.... Bug No.2 if you want so...and then

```
team.setTeamName(teamName);
DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));
.
.
.
team.addPlayer(player3);
team.addPlayer(player4);
team.addPlayer(player5);
```

And again, you're only setting a new teamName of your first instance of Team, and then your're creating a new Team for DivisionOne. So far, Bug No.3 ;)
But you're putting some new players to the "old" team instance, same one as above.

All in all, your created "team" instance has nothing to do with your DivisionOne. So, you created an instance of Team, putting all together six players in it and you call 2 times showTeamPlayers on it. No surprise after all, that the first 3 players are still in there....

Last Point:

```
League DivisionOne = new League("Division One");
```

should be

```
League divisionOne = new League("Division One");
```

Since a variable never starts with a capital letter, "DivisionOne" could also be a static class (cause classes are always starts with capita letters...)

Comment: Thanks for that, Just wondering though for example how can I over come these bugs? If you could try and explain for bug number one, then I can take you advice and attempt at solving the other bugs. Actually someone has beaten you to it, thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 2):

Well bugs are already mentioned by PaddyG. Here is the soln:

Replace this code:

```
teamName = UserInput.readString();

team.setTeamName(teamName);


//Add the team
DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));
```

with:

```
teamName = UserInput.readString();

team = new Team(teamName);

//Add the team
DivisionOne.addTeam(team);
```

And also replace:

```
teamName = UserInput.readString();

team.setTeamName(teamName);

//Add the team
DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));


Player player3 = new Player(3, "Creamer");
Player player4 = new Player(4, "Matt");
Player player5 = new Player(5, "John");
```

with:

```
teamName = UserInput.readString();

team = new Team(teamName);

//Add the team
DivisionOne.addTeam(team);


Player player3 = new Player(3, "Creamer");
Player player4 = new Player(4, "Matt");
Player player5 = new Player(5, "John");
```

As you can see in the above code that we updated the `team` variable with the new instance for the new team. And this new instance is added to the `DivisionOne`. When you are doing `DivisionOne.addTeam(new Team(teamName));` you are creating and adding a brand new instance to 
 DivisionOne but the instance to which you are adding players is a different one (held by the `team` variable). So the soln is to create a new instance and set the variable `team` with the  this newly created instance and then add players to it and add it to `DivisionOne`.

Comment: Also would you have to create a new instance of team to remove a team that already exists?

Comment: Nope. But have to have a way to to locate the team either by using team name and then later searching for it in the ArrayList. Say your DivisionOne is storing Team in an HashMap<String,Team> where key String is the Team Name and value is the team. Then you can easily remove it by saying `teamMap.remove(teamName)`.

Comment: I'm also storing the teams in an Array List.

Comment: If you are storing in ArrayList then you have to loop through it and compare each team's name in the list and when you found it just remove it. Like `Team teamToDelete; for(Team team : teams) if(team.getName().equals(teamName)) { teamToDelete = team; break; } teams.remove(teamToDelete);` In this code we are trying to first find the instance in the ArrayList for the teamName to delete and then we call the api on ArrayList to actually remove it.

Comment: Say I was to ask the user to ender a char to list the players for a team, would I need to create a new instance of team each time?
Because as it stands, I can add a team and the players, and list them fine. But if I create another team and try to list the first created team they show blank, even though there are players in there!

Comment: No instances are created only for new objects. since you already have objects created you dont need to. You code should look like `for(Team  team:teams) showTeamPlayers(team)`. For further understanding pls refer to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

> I've had no end of trouble trying to get this working. One particular
>   problem I've encountered is that every time I create a team object,
>   and add a player object to it, then create another team object and
>   another player but if I list the players for that new team it shows
>   the previous player added to the first team as well as the new player.

Make sure the team objects don't share any fields. Maybe you were using a 'static' field for the list that holds the players? If you declare a field static, it will be shared among all team instances, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code would be helpful, but given your description, I'd imagine starting with something like this as an example:

```
// Team.java
public class Team {
   private String name;
   private List<Player> players;

   public Team(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.players = new ArrayList<Player>();
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public List<Player> getPlayers() {
       return players;
   }
}

// Player.java
public class Player {
   private String name;

   public Player(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}

// Main.java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Team team1 = new Team("Team #1");
      Team team2 = new Team("Team #2");
      team1.getPlayers().add(new Player("Bob"));
      team2.getPlayers().add(new Player("Joe"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Kaleb's answer, but I'll give you an alternative (if you want)...

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    protected int speed;
    protected int health;

    public Player(String name, int speed, int health) {
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.health = health;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Player> team1 = new HashMap<Player>();
        Map<Player> team2 = new HashMap<Player>();
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the player followed by its speed, health, and team number:");
        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(",");
        String name = sc.next();
        int speed = sc.nextInt();
        int health = sc.nextInt();
        if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
            team1.put(new Player(name, speed, health));
        } else {
            team2.put(new Player(name, speed, health));
        }
    }
}
```